# How to configure Apache Server with three applications and one domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, webserver, shared-hosting

I want to host three different applications, we call them *web*, *admin* and *api* on a shared hosting which an apache web-server. The domain is called `www.example.com`.

- `www.example.com` should point to the *web* app
- `www.example.com/admin` should point to the *admin* app
- `www.example.com/api` should point to the *api* app

For better maintenance, I want those three apps within different folders on the server. My dream folder structure would be:

```
/ ......................... root of the server
/www_test_folder/web ...... web app; www.test.com points to it
/www_test_folder/api ...... api app; www.test.com/api points to it
/www_test_folder/admin .... admin app; www.test.com/admin points to it
```

I tried some `.htaccess` configurations but without any success; so my general question ...

Is this even possible? And if yes, how would the `.htaccess` will look like?

Comment: I think it should be, but normally you would do `admin.test.com` or `api.test.com`. I'm just learning apache server myself, so don't know much else

Comment: .htaccess is the wrong tool for the job.  You should either adjust your folder structure to match your URL structure, or you should configure the paths in `httpd.conf` where you can use [alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directives.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller They are in a shared server environment so using `Alias` in the server config is not an option. The `/admin` and `/api` URLs already do match the folder structure so it's only the "web app" URLs that need to be rewritten. (Keeping the app in a separate subdirectory - instead of root - does have some advantages.) However, using subdomains as @Anston suggests (pointing to directories outside of the main document root) would probably be the cleanest solution in a shared server environment.

Comment: "one shared Apache server" is not the same thing as shared hosting.  It sounds to me like they have control over the server.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding; I meant shared hosting; which is a limited access to a server with ftp and restricted ssh. updated my question accordingly

Comment: of course using subdomains is a good solution; unfortunately having limited ssl certificates it isn't possible to make more (sub)domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `/www_test_folder` is your `DocumentRoot` - the directory to which the hostname `www.example.com` already points to.

You shouldn't need to do anything specific for the URLs/routes `/admin` and `/api` (other than perhaps creating an *exception*) since these point directly to the subdirectories of the same name. But since these map to physical subdirectories, the root "canonical" URL of these apps must include a trailing slash. ie. `/admin/`, not `/admin` (otherwise mod_dir will issue a 301 redirect to append a trailing slash).

That just leaves you to implement an internal rewrite for the "web app" to internally rewrite requests from the root to the `/web` subdirectory. This can be achieved in the root `.htaccess` file (although exactly how this is implemented can depend on the apps themselves and whether they have their own `.htaccess` file in the relevant app subdirectory).

For example:

```
# /.htaccess (root)

RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite requests that do not map to "/admin/..." or "/api/..." to the "/web" subdir
# Also exclude any requests that map directly to physical files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule !^(web|admin|api)($|/) web%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The filesystem checks (the first two *conditions*) may or may not be necessary, depending on how the sub apps are configured. In fact, if each app has its own `.htaccess` file (in the relevant subdirectory) that uses mod_rewrite (a front-controller pattern or canonical redirect for instance) then the above rule could potentially be reduced to a simple one-liner. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^ web%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The presence of an `.htaccess` file (containing mod_rewrite directives) in the subdirectory prevents erroneous rewrites that could otherwise result in a rewrite-loop. This is because mod_rewrite is not inherited by default.

You then need to prevent direct/user access to the `/web` subdirectory. Although this subdirectory should be entirely hidden from the user, if it did get inadvertently exposed it could cause a duplicate content issue. This means that any assets (images, CSS, JS, etc.) should not reference the `/web` subdirectory publicly.

This could be achieved in the same root `.htaccess` file (if the web app did not itself have its own `.htaccess` file), however, it would be preferable to  do this in the web app's own `.htaccess` file at `/web/.htaccess`.

For example:

```
# /web/.htaccess

# Prevent direct access to this subdirectory 
# Redirect any requests for "/web/anything" back to the root, ie. "/anything"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the relative URL-path, the part after the `/web/` prefix. The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var ensures that only direct requests from the client are caught and not internally rewritten requests by the rewrite in the root `.htaccess` file.

---

### Alternatively, use subdomains

However, having said all the above, if these are 3 entirely separate apps then it would arguably be preferable to use subdomains instead (this should be possible in most shared server environments).

You would have two subdomains: `admin.example.com` and `api.example.com`. These subdomains need to point to two subdirectories within your shared hosting account. However, these subdirectories do not need to be (and should not be) within the main domains public HTML space (document root), they can point to subdirectories *outside* of the main domains document root (even in a shared server environment). (Otherwise, you potentially have a duplicate content issue again, which requires additional rules to resolve.)

The web app would simply be in the main domains document root, not in a `/web` subdirectory.

This enables the 3 apps to be entirely separate. No additional rewriting/`.htaccess` files are necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I tried it on the server and actually could make it work. Thanks a lot.